# CSS <h> Margin help?

Tags: css, margin

I have a margin used to space some headings down away from an image, but despite this method working on other pages, it does not in this instance.
I know there are plenty of alternative solutions, but am curious as to what is wrong with this one. Can anyone help?

```
<div class="column" style="width: 237px">
<img src="img.jpg" alt="" title="img" width="237" height="300" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-84" />

<h1 style="margin-top: 40px">VAL</h1>
<span class="detailhead">Heading 1</span> <span class="detail">Detail 1</span><br />
<span class="detailhead">Heading 2</span> <span class="detail">Detail 2</span>
</div>
```

These are all the additional class declarations:
The image class has no associated style (class was inserted by Wordpress).

```
h1 {
    font-size: 17px;
}

span.detailhead{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#000000;
}


span.detail {
    position: relative; 
    top: 1.5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000000; 
}

.column {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is the offending style i overlooked:

```
img {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

A more specific selector fixed the issue.
Thanks to all for helping me with this seriously schoolboy error!

Comment: Hi @jack, can you add what the css classes "alignnone size-full wp-image-84" declare please?

Comment: Hi @jack it might be the styles from wordpress are conflicting. Would you be able to post those as well? You can get from an element inspector like firebug or ie developer toolbar etc, if that helps.

Comment: if you save your HTML and CSS into a new page, it works. what's different about this particular page?

Comment: I'd actually shot myself in the foot with a blanket img{} style that was conflicting. Big thanks for your comments, they helped me dig that out.

Comment: @jack cool, glad you got to the bottom of it.

Comment: @jack Is your problem all solved now?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try adding a `style="display:block"` to the `img` tag?

Comment: Thanks, but no effect in this instance :S

Comment: I think you were onto something here (see comments above). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If your using chrome or safari for testing: use the element inspector to check wether your inline setting is not overruled by an !important; declaration in one of the classes.

Edit: To quickly test this you can also add " !important;" to your inline css.

Comment: Thanks, I think conflict must be the issue here, though I don't have any !important; declarations, is it possible the setting is still overuled?

Comment: If there are no !important declarations in your CSS I don't think so. In that case the inline CSS has the preference over the stylesheets. What are the margin settings on the image? Maybe it has a negative _margin-bottom_

Comment: Strange! I don't think there are any conflicts anyway, I've posted the related styles in the Question now.

Comment: In that case, I would use the element inspector of Chrome/Safari/Firefox to examine the elements. Look at the "computed style" and check the differences between the two pages. I'm guessing it's either a float or margin setting causing this.

Comment: Thanks, I'd not fully utilised these features before, very helpful!